# How to get timezone offset in Carbon when not working with dates?

Tags: php, php-carbon, timezone-offset

I'm creating an app which allows people to reserve an hour of time each day.

It's not really a calendar, as it's only showing 7 days (Mon - Sun) and the hours of the day (0-23). See the screenshot for reference.

Anyone, anywhere can register. So a person in Miami can reserve `12:00 - 13:00` on `Sunday` and that will be stored in the db as UTC. When someone in New York goes to look at this "schedule" they will see that someone has reserved an hour on Sunday at 12:00 pm.

However, if someone in Los Angeles is looking at the schedule, they will also see that that hour has been reserved on Sunday, but it will need to be offset for their timezone, so they'll see 9:00 am has been reserved. This is working as intended.

Now here's the problem: if someone in Bangkok reserves an hour on Sunday, how do I get that 14-hour offset so that someone in Los Angeles sees it as Monday instead of Sunday, with the correct time?

I've been racking my brain on this and haven't been able to come up with a solution because we're on a fixed number of days and are not working with dates, just days and hours.

#### The functions

```
function daysOfTheWeek() {
    return ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
}

function daysInTheWeek() {

    $days = [];

    for($i=1; $i<=7; $i++) {
        $days[$i] = $i;
    }

    return $days;
}

function hoursinTheDay() {

    $hours = [];

    for($i=0; $i<=23; $i++) {
        $hours[$i] = $i;
    }

    return $hours;
}
```

#### The code

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
$hoursReserved = \DB::table('schedule')->get();

echo '<table border="1" cellpadding="2">';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>Hour</th>';

// print the days of the week (Monday - Sunday)
foreach(daysOfTheWeek() as $daw) {
    echo '<th>'.$daw.'</th>';
}
echo '</tr>';

foreach(hoursinTheDay() as $hour) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>';

    // print the hours of the day (24 hour format)
    echo Carbon::createFromFormat('H',$hour)->format('H:i').' - '.Carbon::createFromFormat('H',$hour)->addHour(1)->format('H:i');
    echo '</td>';

    // loop through the number of days in the week (1-7)
    foreach(daysInTheWeek() as $day) {

        // loop through the reserved hours
        foreach($hoursReserved as $reservedHour) {

            // if the hour reserved is in Bangkok, and the person is viewing it in Los Angeles, how to show that offset?

            // stub in the timezones for testing
            // $start = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $reservedHour->start_at)->timezone('Asia/Bangkok')->format('H:i:s');
            // $now = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $reservedHour->start_at)->timezone('America/Los_Angeles')->format('H:i:s');

            // dd($now);

            if(($reservedHour->day == $day) && ($reservedHour->start_at == $hour)) {
                // hour is reserved - this is working for local time
                // I stripped out the conversion for NYC to LA for brevity
                echo '<td>X</td>';
            } else {
                // hour is not reserved
                echo '<td></td>';
            }
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';

dd();

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

#### screenshot

[image: table]

Comment: You *must* have a full date because the timezone offset is dependent on the time of the year, and a number of other factors.

Comment: @Evert Thanks, I figured that would be the case. This is what the client wants; any suggestions on how I can achieve this with a 7 day fixed system?

Comment: You need to pick a date. Maybe you always pick 'the next monday', but bear in mind that there are weeks in the year where the offset for one country changes an hour, but the offset for another doesn't. Discuss this with the client, because what the client _exactly_ wants is just not possible, possibly because the client is unaware of international timezone rules.

Comment: @Evert Thank you very much for your advice. :)

Comment: 1/ It exist timezones like +12:45 or +7:30, that means my 12:00-13:00 can be your 06:30-07:30.

2/ Daylight saving time change during year for some countries only and not on the same dates.

For those 2 reason, you app cannot work this way for an international use. You have to rethink it, with minute offset at least and handle a real calendar because of the DST.